# driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss(); not working on MS Edge

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert, microsoft-edge

When I run my test in MS Edge,  I want to click on cancel when there is a popup and I tried to do that with:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Add relevant HTML and maybe a screenshot of a popup. Popup might be a `window`, not an `alert`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to induce *WebDriverWait* with *ExpectedConditions* as [`alertIsPresent()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent--) as follows :

- Accept Alert :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions. alertIsPresent()).accept();
  ```
- Dismiss Alert :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions. alertIsPresent()).dismiss();
  ```